# automorphism groups of the orthogonal group and special orthogonal group

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

What are the automorphism groups of the groups $SO(3)$ and $O(3)$, that is, the 3x3 orthogonal matrices and the 3x3 orthogonal matrices with determinant 1. Thanks

Comment: In [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/a/14743/34894), it is ultimately stated that the outer automorphism group of $\mathfrak{so}_3$ is trivial, i.e. only automorphisms of the *lie algebra* associated with $SO(3)$ and $O(3)$ are the inner automorphisms (since the associated Dynkin diagram has type $B$).  For simply connected Lie groups, knowing this information gives us the automorphisms of the group.  Unfortunately, $SO(3)$ is not simply connected.

Comment: My hunch would be, though, that the only automorphisms of $O(3)$ and $SO(3)$ are inner-automorphisms.

Comment: The complete answer for $SO(n)$ is here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59910/automorphisms-of-son-mathbb-r

Comment: @GreginGre See Jason's comment; the solution that you have linked is problematic.

Comment: -1, what ideas do you have, what have you tried, what is the context of the problem (and what is the ground field, although I could assume it's $\mathbb R$)?