# Explicit automorphism map of $SO(n;\mathbb{R})$ for $n \neq 2,8$?

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, lie-groups, automorphism-group, group-extensions

How do we construct a precise map of inner + outer automorphism of special orthogonal group $SO(n;\mathbb{R})$?

- $d=2$; We can look at $SO(2;\mathbb{R})=U(1)$ which is abelian, and we know the inner
  $$
  Inn(SO(2;\mathbb{R}))=SO(2;\mathbb{R})/Z(SO(2;\mathbb{R}))=1
  $$
  $$
  Out(SO(2;\mathbb{R}))=\mathbb{Z}/2
  $$
  The total $Aut(SO(2;\mathbb{R}))=Inn(SO(2;\mathbb{R})) \rtimes Out(SO(2;\mathbb{R}))=\mathbb{Z}/2$
  We have no $Inn(SO(2;\mathbb{R}))$ except the identity map.
  I believe that we can get the $Out(SO(2;\mathbb{R}))=\mathbb{Z}/2$ by flipping $t \to -t$ in
  $$
  U(1)=\{\exp(i t) | t \in [0, 2 \pi)\}
  \to
  \{\exp(-i t) | t \in [0, 2 \pi)\}.
  $$
  I wish to see explicit answer like the above for my following questions ---
- other $n$ but $n\neq 2,8$,

> Question 1: How do we construct the inner automorphism map explicitly  (if my result is correct?)
> $$
> Inn(SO(n;\mathbb{R}))=SO(n;\mathbb{R})/Z(SO(n;\mathbb{R})) =\left\{
> \begin{array}{ll}
> SO(n;\mathbb{R})/\mathbb{Z}/2, &n \in even\\
> SO(n;\mathbb{R}) ,  &d \in odd
> \end{array} \right.
> $$

> Question 2: How do we construct the outer automorphism map explicitly
> $$
> Out(SO(n;\mathbb{R}))=\mathbb{Z}/2 
> $$
> Given the parametrization of  $SO(n;\mathbb{R})$ how to map to itself via the Out map?

> Question 3: How do we construct the total automorphism map explicitly
> $$
> Aut(SO(n;\mathbb{R}))=Inn(SO(n;\mathbb{R})) \rtimes Out(SO(n;\mathbb{R}))?
> $$
> Given the parametrization of  $SO(n;\mathbb{R})$ how to map to itself via the Aut map?

p.s. Possible useful link but with not explicit (not enough) constructions in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/235758/automorphism-group-of-real-orthogonal-lie-groups