# All actions of $SO(3)$ on $S^2$

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, group-actions, principal-bundles

There are two obvious (smooth left) actions of $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ on $S^2$. There is the standard action by which $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ acts by 3D rotations on the standard embedding of $S^2$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and there is the trivial action in which $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ leaves the points of $S^2$ unchanged. It feels like these are the only two options. Is that intuition correct?

Comment: What kind of actions are you allowing? Actions by isometries?

Comment: Ideally I just want to require that the actions are smooth, but not necessarily say that $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ has to act linearly or by isometries on $S^2$. That is, the action should be a map from $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ to $\mathrm{Diff}(S^2)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there are other smooth actions:

Fix $g\in\mathrm{SO}(3)$ and denote by $(h,x)\mapsto h.x$ the standard action. Then

$$
\mathrm{SO}(3) \times\mathbb S^2\to\mathbb S^2,\;\;(h,x)\mapsto ghg^{-1}.x
$$
is also a smooth left action, which is not the trivial action and in general different from the standard one.

Comment: Great, thank you so much! I have a follow up question. It seems if $f:\mathrm{SO}(3) \rightarrow \mathrm{SO}(3)$ is an automorphism then $(h,x)\mapsto f(h).x$ is a smooth action. From this [https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59910/automorphisms-of-son-mathbb-r](other post), it seems that every such automophism can be described by the map you define with an appropriately chosen $g$. Do you happen to know if this is exhaustive i.e. are there any smooth group actions not of the form you gave?

Comment: @ForgetfulFunctor More generally, for any fixed diffeomorphism $\varphi:\mathbb S^2\to\mathbb S^2$ one can define the action $(h,x)\mapsto \varphi(h.\varphi^{-1}(x))$, which is smooth, since it is given by the composition of smooth maps$\varphi\circ\mathrm{std}\circ(\mathrm{id}\times\varphi^{-1}):\mathrm{SO}(3) \times\mathbb S^2\to\mathrm{SO}(3)\times\mathbb S^2\to\mathbb S^2\to\mathbb S^2$. This should give a lot of other examples.